# Delphi creating a paint event canvas issues

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

When I look at `TWinControl`, the `Canvas` is blanked out with `clBtnFace` and then the `WM_PAINT` is called. This causes an unavoidable flicker that I do not need. Also the canvas given allows drawing over the scroll bars making the scroll bars to be redrawn after a `WM_PAINT` event and creating more flicker.

`GetMetrics` and internal scrollbar Info gives the true canvas size. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I understand an `HDC` is a handle on the form that has a rectangular canvas to print on. So I'm thinking:

1. how do I create a new `HDC` with a smaller width and height and not move the Top Left corner. I want to remove flicker by not using a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message if possible and not printing over scrollbars by allocating a newly sized `HDC` and then to set the Delphi canvas handle with the correct `HDC`.
2. using a windows bitmap that I do not know if I should use and set the Bitmap canvas size for a `BitBlt()` copy as, TWinControl (Below).

   ```
   DC := GetDC(0);
   MemBitmap := CreateCompatibleBitmap(DC, ClientRect.Right, ClientRect.Bottom);
   ReleaseDC(0, DC);
   MemDC := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
   OldBitmap := SelectObject(MemDC, MemBitmap);
   try
     DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
     Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND, MemDC, MemDC);
     Message.DC := MemDC;
     WMPaint(Message);
     Message.DC := 0;
     BitBlt(DC, 0, 0, ClientRect.Right, ClientRect.Bottom, MemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
     EndPaint(Handle, PS);
   finally
     SelectObject(MemDC, OldBitmap);
     DeleteDC(MemDC);
     DeleteObject(MemBitmap);
   end;
   ```

I do not know what option is better in a flicker free result and how to implement it in Delphi.

Comment: So you are writing  a custom TWinControl and the blob of code you are showing is the paint method?  How about you make this question a bit clearer, it's a mess. Or are you painting in a Paintbox?

Comment: You are overthinking things. If what you said were true, all standard controls would have bad flickering as you have described. That is simply not true. Whatever is causing your flicker issue is likely in your own drawing code, not in how `TWinControl` manages its `Canvas`.  Please show your actual code that you are having trouble with.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to give you help

Answer (score 1):

> ...the `Canvas` is blanked out with `clBtnFace`...

The background color is adjustable with setting `Brush.Color`.

> and then the `WM_PAINT` is called. This causes an unavoidable flicker...

This can be prevented by by-passing the `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.

> How do I create a new `HDC` with a smaller width and height?

That is not possible. A device context has no size. It is only limitted by the window which hosts it.

> The canvas given allows drawing over the scroll bars making the scroll bars to be redrawn after a `WM_PAINT` event.

Native scroll bars are drawn by the system in `WM_NCPAINT`. If you can draw over them, then you have gotten a device context of the whole window, not its client space.

But overall speaking, the solution is really simple: do not draw beyond the client region of a window.

And as a tip: I suggest that you derive your control from `TCustomControl` instead of `TWinControl` because that class has already a canvas you can draw on which eliminates all your WinAPI code.

Comment: Yes TCustomControl descendant, Remy Lebeau I do not know where to start really and I do not know the API calls, when I read origin or extent I have no idea what that means.  The WM_ERASEBKGND message is what I need to get away from!!!! NGLN. I can use the standard RecreateWin and my handle is rock solid but it flickers badly as I explained. infact I have used the canvas handle in on mousedown and keydown too but do not recommend it. You cannot run the handle off a thread made in a paint event.

Comment: I still have two options of design use a blank canvas and copy or Blacking out little area's just before filling it in as I rebuild it.

Comment: also 'DC := GetDC(0);' using 0 does not make sence to me.

Comment: '    DC := GetDC(0);
    MemBitmap := CreateCompatibleBitmap(DC, ClientPoint.X, ClientPoint.Y);
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
    MemDC := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
    OldBitmap := SelectObject(MemDC, MemBitmap);
    try
      DC := BeginPaint(Handle, PS);
      Canvas.Lock;
    try
      Canvas.Handle := MemDC;
      try
        Paint;
      finally
        Canvas.Handle := 0;
      end;
    finally
      Canvas.Unlock;
    end;
      BitBlt(DC, 0, 0, ClientRect.Right, ClientRect.Bottom, MemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
      EndPaint(Handle, PS);
finally
SelectObject(MemDC, OldBitmap);
DeleteDC(MemDC); ..etc
'

Comment: `GetDC(0)` gets the device context of the desktop, that's the painting surface of your whole screen. No wonder you paint over scroll bars. Please edit your question and include more information: what exactly do you want to do, when exactly, and with what kind of controls? Are you painting a custom component, or are you painting in an event of existing controls? Your code lacks a method name and signature, so we cannot estimate when it runs. We should not estimate though, you should explain better what you want and what exactly you are doing. Please be specific. We cannot reed your mind.

Comment: I have realised I need a :- RedrawWindow(handle, @Rect,.............
Statement But Do not know how to get a HRGN hrgnUpdate for it
RedrawWindow has a flag to not call the WM_paint message that I want to use. I believe RedrawWindow will allow drawing to the canvas. I do not want to use the Perform(WM_ERASEBKGND... because of flickering

Comment: Instead of answering our questions or explaining your problem a little better, you reside into finding things out yourself. That's all fine by me, but whatever it is you are trying to do, I'm pretty sure you aren't in need of `RedrawWindow`. If you really want our help (which I imagine, because you post on this very site), then please try a little harder to let us help you by answering our questions and being specific about your problem. Right now I'm unable to comment on your last comment, because I'm totally lost on what your problem really is.

Comment: I've reread the full thread, I guess the subject matter is very complicated in itself, As a delphi programer i'm not use to RedrawWindow and many other openGPL commands. But I cannot see how I could have asked the question any better at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, but that's really disappointing. [Warren P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028154/delphi-creating-a-paint-event-canvas-issues/35036701?noredirect=1#comment57782646_35028154), [Remy Lebeau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028154/delphi-creating-a-paint-event-canvas-issues/35036701?noredirect=1#comment57784782_35028154), [David Heffernan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028154/delphi-creating-a-paint-event-canvas-issues/35036701?noredirect=1#comment57791034_35028154) and myself ask a dozen specific questions, and after reading it over, none of them can be answered? Sad.

Comment: I want to announce I have a descendant of TCustomControl that fully works, I have added scrollbars, a timer event and using windows.InvalidateRect and redrawWindow I have near no flicker. It's a rock solid canvas.handle that is the base to make anything I like. It's cool, it's amazing and it's very good. David Heffernan's comments looking back was always in the way of what I have now achieved. windows.InvalidateRect I can set what part of the canvas I want to update even as the rect is the client area.